# How to transfer data wireless between extra peripherals to MacBook through WiFi?

Tags: network, wifi, usb, thunderbolt

Apple keeps things simple with its only two thunderbolt 3/USB type C ports to connect to peripherals which is great.

Few cases

1. I want to transfer/access data from my old SATA HDD from my MacBook
2. I want to transfer/access data from an android device from my MacBook
3. I want to transfer/access data from memory stick like SD card/pen drive from my MacBook

We can use any third party "USB Type C hub" like shown in the images below

[image]

Is there any similar device that has all these ports/most of the ports but instead of using two Thunderbolt 3/USB Type C ports uses WiFi to connect to these devices?

Hardware is prone to wear and tear so want to use the ports as less as possible

Comment: Are you looking for a NAS like synology that can host external drives connected or just want to transfer the data one time?

Comment: Not one time, but frequently. I looked at NAS like synology but it is for data back don't know if it does it wireless. I want to be able connect devices wireless to my macbook without frequently sticking USB type C hub every time I want to access data on memory stick or connect my android device

Comment: I think you're either worrying too much about "wear & tear" or you have a proven track record of being rough on peripherals. I've had the same USB hub for over a decade with no signs of it quitting yet.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not worried about USB hub, but my MacBook port. As any apple product has a price for its high quality and repairs.

Comment: I've never worn out a Mac port either. The oldest Mac here is now 14 years...

Comment: @Tetsujin My first ever apple product so more concerned

Comment: I think you're worrying unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Any NAS would work for this. Professionally, Synology has a great name. To save wear and tear you could also get a CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 / USB 4 dock so that you have one high quality cable that connects so you make fewer connections to the Mac.

Cheaper NAS have less robust support for scheduling / backups than the Synology software.